# Extracting specific rows from the data frame in R

Tags: r, extract

I have the following like data in a tab-delimted text file named *original*

```
Name     Symbol       Value
abcd       A            56   
de45       C            67
ji98       H            90
k9ug       K            43
phzt       L            98
prex       P            21
kadf       T            32
```

Also I have list of selected Symbols stored in another tab delimited text file named *duplicate*

```
Symbol     Description
 K            Intel
 P            Diary
 C            Cape
 S            Sheath
 A            Aim
```

I want to extract the rows from *original* file which has same Symbol with *duplicate*. I want my output like the following:

```
Name     Symbol       Value
abcd       A            56   
de45       C            67
k9ug       K            43
prex       P            21
```

I tried using the following code but some how I could not get any results or only the row of *A*. Here is the code which I have used

```
result <- original[original$Symbol %in% duplicate$Symbol,]
```

Could anyone please help me.

Comment: Shouldn't the variable in the `duplicate` dataframe be `Symbol`, not `symbol`?

Comment: Check your spelling of "original" ;-)

Comment: @James, that would make a merge easier, but looking at the supplied attempt at extracting the rows, the OP is aware of the difference in capitalization.

Comment: @ James I changed the  spelling but I got the "<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) " as my result..I m ready to provide further information also..I dont know where I went wrong

Comment: @Thileepan, I hope you didn't change the spelling for *both* James's suggestion and mine. If you change as James suggested, then it doesn't match the data you provided. Read my updated answer with the assumptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with a simple `merge`:

```
merge(original, duplicate, by.x="Symbol", by.y="symbol")
#   Symbol Name Value Description
# 1      A abcd    56         Aim
# 2      C de45    67        Cape
# 3      K k9ug    43       Intel
# 4      P prex    21       Diary
```

You can manually drop the `Description` column before or after merging if it is not relevant.

Also, I don't know if this is a problem with the question as posted or if it is a problem with your code, but:

```
original[original$Symbol %in% duplicate$symbol, ]
#   Name Symbol Value
# 1 abcd      A    56
# 2 de45      C    67
# 4 k9ug      K    43
# 6 prex      P    21
```

Of course, you have to spell `original` correctly, which you did not!

#### Assumptions

1. The correct capitalization of the word "symbol" in `names(original)` shows up with an upper-case S (`Symbol`).
2. The correct capitalization of the word "symbol" in `names(duplicate)` shows up with a lower-case s (`symbol`).

If both are capitalized, then you can use either of the following solutions:

```
merge(original, duplicate)
original[original$Symbol %in% duplicate$Symbol, ]
```

Comment: @ mrdwab I changed the spelling but I got the "<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) " as my result..I m ready to provide further information also..I dont know where I went wrong